# Specflow not working for strings that need escape characters in example

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow, gherkin

I am writing a specflow scenario integrated with selenium. Following is the scenarion which i need to execute:

```
Scenario Outline: MVT scenario 1
    Given I am on the Homepage
    When I navigate to a product page
    Then the pagesource should contain the <search_string>
    Examples: 
    | search_string |
    | <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> |
```

When I execute the above scenario with the supplied string:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

Then the script starts selenium webdriver and stops it abruptly without executing the complete scenario.

The search_string is used in the code for validation as follows :

```
Assert.That(_productPageObject.GetPageSource().Contains(searchString));
```

If I am passing any other string (which does not need any escape characters) for the example, then the scenario executes completely. 
Has anyone faced such a problem before?Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add the code where you are using `search_string`

Comment: @Sam Holder : I have updated the question to include the line of code where search_string is used for validation. Thanks.

Comment: It's an issue with gherkin: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cukes/LABvh6EtjPY

Answer (score -1):

May be you need to use @ character (for avoiding the escape characters) like we use to did when we pass some url in C# code.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Down voting because you give no clarity on where to use the `@` symbol